# What should be a secret key (or an authentication key) that passed to `NewCookieStore()` in `gorilla/sessions`?

Tags: go, gorilla

In [gorilla/sessions](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions#NewCookieStore), `func NewCookieStore(keyPairs ...[]byte) *CookieStore` is a used to create a new CookieStore. But I don't actually know what is a secret key (or an authentication key).

The description had said that :

> It is recommended to use an authentication key with 32 or 64 bytes.

Therefore, is this means that I can randomly push any string with length of 32 or 64? How do you choose your authentication key?

Answer (score 4):

From the end of that paragraph in the documentation for `NewCookieStore`:

> Use the convenience function securecookie.GenerateRandomKey() to create strong keys.

Use [`securecookie.GenerateRandomKey`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/securecookie#GenerateRandomKey)